# How can I access the title of UNNotificationContent?

Tags: swift, unnotificationrequest

```
func CalendarTriggeredNotification(givenDate: Date, roomName: String, itemName: String) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Freshness Check."
    content.subtitle = "Room: \(roomName). Check on \(itemName)"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    let dateComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: givenDate)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: false)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
        print(requests)
    }
    
    successNotificationBanner(title: "Reminder Saved")
}
```

**Prints:**

> [<UNNotificationRequest: 0x600003c502a0; identifier: 62F8BB2B-FC5D-40AE-8C43-6AFEEFBD9F0B, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x600000ee6a00; title: , subtitle: , body: (null), summaryArgument: , summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
> ), badge: (null), sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x6000019df170>, realert: 0, interruptionLevel: 1, relevanceScore: 0.00, trigger: <UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x6000033efe40; dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x6000030e8330> {
> Calendar Year: 2022
> Month: 7
> Day: 11
> Hour: 11
> Minute: 49, repeats: NO>>]

The title and subtitle read `<'redacted'>`. How can I access them to show pending local notifications to users?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
    for request in requests {
        print("---------------------------------------------")
        print(request.identifier)
        print(request.content.title)
        print(request.content.body)
        print(request.content.subtitle)
        print("---------------------------------------------")
    }
}
```